# What is/are a/some way(s) to combine two for each loops in java? here is a basic example:

Tags: java, arrays

public int combineArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {

```
int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length]; 
int index = 0;

for (int i : a) {
  result[index] = i;
  index++;
}
for (int i : b) { 
  result[index] = i;
  index++; 
}
return result;
```

}
Apologies, here is the correct code.

Comment: Note that you're assuming the arrays are the same length here. You need to decide how to handle different length arrays.

Comment: `System.arraycopy`

Comment: @BackSlash I was thinking of just append one to the other :/, to interleaving them

Comment: Method should return an array, i.e. the signature should be `public int[] combineArrays(int[] a, int[] b)` instead

Comment: `Stream.of(a, b).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray()`

Comment: By the way, if you aren't really doing this for an assignment, I'd highly recommend using something like: al=new ArrayList(a);al.addAll(b);  I recommend leaving it as an ArrayList when you are done and would even say that a and b should already be ArrayLists.  Do you have a strong reason to use arrays directly??? (Hint: There almost isn't a strong reason to use arrays directly except when directed because you're supposed to be learning how to code.)